# Help with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, classname

I have this sample text, which is retrieved from the class name on an html element:

```
rich-message err-test1 erroractive
rich-message err-test2 erroractive
rich-message erroractive err-test1
err-test2 rich-message erroractive
```

I am trying to match the "test1"/"test2" data in each of these examples. I am currently using the following regex, which matches the "err-test1" type of word. I can't figure out how to limit it to just the data after the hyphen(-).

```
/err-(\S*)/ig
```

Head hurts from banging against this wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I am reading, your code already works.

**`Regex.exec()` returns an array of results on success.**

The first element in the array (index 0) returns the entire string, after which all `()` enclosed elements are pushed into this array.

```
var string = 'rich-message err-test1 erroractive';
var regex = new RegExp('err-(\S*)', 'ig');
var result = regex.exec(string);

alert(result[0]) --> returns err-test1
alert(result[1]) --> returns test1
```

Comment: Bloody hell, I'm an idiot. I have been using .match() instead of .exec(). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try 'err-([^ \n\r]*)' - but are you sure that it is the regex that is the problem? Are you using the whole result, not just the first capture?

Comment: The only bit that I need is the text after "err-". I would like to do the match cleanly in a single regex expression instead of matching the entire word then stripping "err-" using an extra method. Sure, it would save time now but its still not fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff after the - should be in the results array.  The first item is all the matching text (e.g. "err-test1") and the next items are the matches from the capture parentheses (e.g. "test1").

```
myregex = /err-(\S*)/ig;
mymatch = myregex.exec("data with matches in it");
testnum = mymatch[1];
```

Here's a [reference site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).